# Accordian Element Height Issue

Tags: javascript, css

I have implemented 2 types of Accordians for my application- 1 Column and 2 Column

Im having a problem with the Static Height for the 1 Column Accordian.  And I've been trying to modify the JavaScript all day but cant seem to get it to work.

The Heights should be dynamic in Height depending upon the amount data, however as you can see the Height is fixed, and some of the data is getting cut off:
http://www.davincispainting.com/whydavincis.aspx
[image]

The other 2 Column Accordian has almost the same JavaScript as the 1 Column Accordian, however the Height is dynanmic depending on how much data there is:
http://www.davincispainting.com/glossary.aspx
[image]

I would provide a Fiddle however the Data is now dynamic:
Here is the JavaScript for the problem Accordian:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $.fn.accordion = function () {
        return this.each(function () {
            $container = $('#mid-featureleft-client');
            $container.find("dt").each(function () {
                var $header = $(this);
                var $selected = $header.next();

                $header.click(function () {
                    $('.active').removeClass('active');
                    $(this).addClass('active');
                    if ($selected.is(":visible")) {
                        $selected.animate({
                            height: 0
                        }, {
                            duration: 300,
                            complete: function () {
                                $(this).hide();
                            }
                        });
                    } else {
                        $unselected = $container.find("dd:visible");
                        $selected.show();
                        var newHeight = heights[$selected.attr("id")];
                        var oldHeight = heights[$unselected.attr("id")];

                        $('<div>').animate({
                            height: 1
                        }, {
                            duration: 300,
                            step: function (now) {
                                var stepSelectedHeight = Math.round(newHeight * now);
                                $selected.height(stepSelectedHeight);
                                $unselected.height(oldHeight + Math.round((newHeight - oldHeight) * now) - Math.round(newHeight * now));
                            },
                            complete: function () {
                                $unselected.hide().css({
                                    height: 0
                                });
                            }
                        });
                    }
                    return false;
                });
            });
            // Iterate over panels, save heights, hide all.
            var heights = new Object();
            $container.find("dd").each(function () {

                $this = $(this);
                $this.css("overflow", "hidden");
                heights[$this.attr("id")] = $this.height();
                $this.hide().css({
                    height: 0
                });
            });
        });
    };

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.getJSON('FaqsJson.ashx?factType=2', function (datas) {
            var str_one = "";
            str_one = "<dl>"

            $.each(datas, function () {
               str_one += "<dt class=\"glossquestion\"><a href=\"javascript://\" class=\"questionLink\">" + this['Question'] + "</a></dt>";
               str_one += "<dd class=\"glossanswer\" style=\"-webkit-margin-start:0px\"><div class=\"answerbox\">" + this['Answer'] + "</div></dd>";
            });
           str_one += "</dl>"; 

            $("#glossary_first").html(str_one);
            $("#mid-featureleft-client").accordion();
        });        
    });
</script>
```

Here is the relevent HTML:

```
<div id="mid-feature-client">
    <div id="mid-featureleft-client">
            <div id="glossary_first" class="controlbox">
            <br /><br />
        </div>
        <div style="clear: both;">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the relevent css:

```
#mid-featureleft-client .controlbox {
    width:546px;
    padding:3px 0 0 6px;
    position:relative; 
    /*background-color:green;*/
}
#mid-featureleft-client .glossarycontrolbox {
    width:260px;
    padding:3px 0 0 6px;
    position:relative; 
    float:left;
    /*background-color:blue;*/
}    
.question-clicked {
    background-color: #CCCCCC;
    color: #0C2A55;
    /*margin-top: 10px;*/
    /*padding: 2px 5px 0;*/
}
.questionLink-clicked {
    color: #0C2A55;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.answerbox {
    padding: 3px 5px 3px 5px;
}

.questionLink {
    color: #0C2A55;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.glossquestion {
    padding: 0 5px 4px 0;
}
.glossanswer {
    background-color: #F9FBFC;
    display: none;
}
#accordion .handle {     
    width: 260px;     
    height: 30px;     
    background-color: orange; 
} 
#accordion .section {     
    width: 260px;     
    height: 445px;     
    background-color: #a9a9a9;    
    overflow: hidden;     
    position: relative; 
} 
dt { 
    /*background-color: #ccc;*/
} 
dd { 
    /*height: 30px;*/
} 
.active {
    background: #a9a9a9; 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with the way you're storing the heights, a bit after this comment:

```
// Iterate over panels, save heights, hide all.
```

Specifically, this line:

```
heights[$this.attr("id")] = $this.height();
```

Your `dd` elements don't have an `id`, so on each iteration of the loop, `heights['']` is being set to the height of the current `dd`.

You should be able to fix it by changing this:

```
$.each(datas, function () {
    str_one += "<dt class=\"glossquestion\"><a href=\"javascript://\" class=\"questionLink\">" + this['Question'] + "</a></dt>";
    str_one += "<dd class=\"glossanswer\" style=\"-webkit-margin-start:0px\"><div class=\"answerbox\">" + this['Answer'] + "</div></dd>";
});
```

to this:

```
var i = 0;
$.each(datas, function () {
    str_one += "<dt class=\"glossquestion\"><a href=\"javascript://\" class=\"questionLink\">" + this['Question'] + "</a></dt>";
    str_one += "<dd id=\"rand_" + i + "\" class=\"glossanswer\" style=\"-webkit-margin-start:0px\"><div class=\"answerbox\">" + this['Answer'] + "</div></dd>";
    i++;
});
```

I'm just going to point out that my fix doesn't seem very jQuery-esque, and your entire code seems complicated for what it's doing.

---

If you changed your JSON to something like this:

```
[{"Question1":"..","Answer1":".."},{"Question2":"..","Answer2":".."}, .. ]
```

You could do this:

```
$.each(datas, function (i, v) {
    str_one += "<dt class=\"glossquestion\"><a href=\"javascript://\" class=\"questionLink\">" + this['Question'] + "</a></dt>";
    str_one += "<dd id=\"Dd" + i + "\" class=\"glossanswer\" style=\"-webkit-margin-start:0px\"><div class=\"answerbox\">" + this['Answer'] + "</div></dd>";
});
```

which is cleaner code than incrementing our own variable `i` inside `$.each`.

Comment: It seemed to do the trick, although its truncating for one of the Data- "Highly Recommended" where there is a single word wrapping.  the Height doesnt accommodate that single word which wraps to the next line.

Comment: Are you putting the new version live? That way, it would be easier to check. Also, this just popped into my head: it would be *far* better to leave the JavaScript as you originally had it, and instead add a unique `id` to each `dd` with your server-side code (like you're doing on your Glossary page).

Comment: @Paul: I added an explanation of what I was talking about. If you can't get it to work, then just stick with what you have.